# Filesystem keeps on going into read only mode

Tags: linux, linux-mint, hard-disk

i have a two 1 To HDDs :

- the first one has windows 10 on it (fast boot disabled) and another partition that i often access from Linux to copy files (a backup partition)
- the second one contains 3 partitions (8GB Swap, 500 GB Linux mint 19.2 installation, +400GB that i use to backup my programming projects)

this last week, i have been getting this issue daily, and today it happened 4 times, the file system would randomly go into read only mode, to fix it i would :

- reboot
- get an `initramfs` console
- type `exit`
- get an `fsck` error on `sdc2` (the linux file system)
- do `fsck /dev/sdc2 -y`
- type `reboot`

I have run SMART diagnosis on my Linux HDD and there are no errors. here what i want to know :

- is my hard drive failing, and the diagnosis is not detecting it ? do i need to replace it ?
- can i fix this issue without replacing my hard drive or reinstalling Linux ? or do i have to do a fresh install
- what is causing the issue ? how do i diagnose ?

**Edit** 
this is the error i'm getting from dmesg

```
[    2.516108] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[    2.516111] ata4.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[    2.516118] ata4.00: cmd a0/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 28
                        Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00res 51/24:03:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[    2.516121] ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
```

I have tried changing the SATA cable and the motherboard's port

**UPDATE**
I backed up my data, reformatted and reinstalled Linux from scratch, dmesg is no longer showing any errors. i'll update you in a couple days.

Thank you !

Comment: Check the logs when that happens. Or even now, usually log rotation means you can access a couple of days (depending on the configuration).

Comment: Related to what @EduardoTrápani suggested: when you see the problem check your `dmesg` logs.  If the drive is failing, you'll see errors there.

Comment: SMART output is not intuitive, please post it.

Comment: Which version of Mint? If 18 or higher, and you don't use Hibernation, your kernel has solved the swap file performance issue and you can eliminate the swap partition and change to a swap file.